# Laravel - Redirect back to login page after login

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication

The laravel keeps redirecting to the login page after the login. There is no error, nothing, it just gets to the login page again. There is no error log as well.

This is the body of the login view:

```
<body>
        <div class="wrapper-page" >
            <div class="panel panel-color panel-primary panel-pages">
                <div class="panel-heading bg-img"> 
                    <div class="bg-overlay"></div>
                    <h3 class="text-center m-t-10 text-white"> Sign In to <strong>My App</strong> </h3>
                </div> 


                <div class="panel-body">
                 <form class="form-horizontal m-t-20" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/auth/login') }}">
                 {!!csrf_field()!!}

                  <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <input class="form-control input-lg" name="email" type="text" required="required" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="E-mail Address">
                        @if ($errors->has('email'))
                            <span class="help-block">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <input class="form-control input-lg" name="password" type="password" required="required" placeholder="Password">
                        @if ($errors->has('password'))
                            <span class="help-block">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                            <input id="checkbox-login" type="checkbox" name="remember">
                            <label for="checkbox-login">
                                Remember me
                            </label>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group text-center m-t-40">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg w-lg waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Log In</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>                                 

    </div>
</div>
```

These are the auth routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {

        Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
        Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
        Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

    });    
});
```

This is the AuthController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Session;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/auth/login';
    protected $redirectTo = '/clients';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }



    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is the config/session.php:

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'database',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => 120,

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
    | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => 'myapp_session',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => "http://myapp.com",

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => false,

];
```

This is the postLogin method, which we did not change:

```
/**
 * Handle a login request to the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->login($request);

}

/**
 * Handle a login request to the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

    if ($throttles && $lockedOut = $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

    if (Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    if ($throttles && ! $lockedOut) {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

I thought there was an issue with the session but the database works, it records the sessions, I don't know how to solve this. Thank you very much.

Comment: try to change the domain in session.php ( in case you didnt) , use ur current domain

Comment: I am using my current domain but it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

In your sessions config you use `'driver' => 'database',`
but `'connection' => null,` is `null` you need to specify connection if you use DB driver
You can find them in `config/database.php`
This causes that the sessions is not stored so user is not Authenticated after login.

Also make sure you have created table in your database for storing sessions

Comment: I changed the connection to `'mysql'` but nothing has changed. I have also tried the other drivers, but I know that the database works and it stores sessions, I can see them all.